# application.bootstrap.scss.erb File Not Found in Rails 7 (No such file or directory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm attempting to change my `application.bootstrap.scss` file to `application.bootstrap.scss.erb` so I can do an ERB case statement to give users a different set of variables depending on the skin they chose with their account.

The website is still appearing on refresh, but none of the CSS is updating.  In my `bin/dev` server I am getting this error:

> Error reading app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss: no
> such file or directory.

I have added this line to my `environments/development.rb` as recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762939/rails-dev-environment-not-updating-html-css-assets-even-after-restarting-server):

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

And I added this line to my `manifest.js`:

```
//= link application.bootstrap.scss.erb
```

Here's the code I have in my `assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss`:

```
<% user_skin = "Ravenclaw Dark" %>

<% case user_skin %>
<% when "Ravenclaw Dark" %>
  @import 'ravenclaw-dark';
<% else %>
  @import 'ravenclaw-light';
<% end %>
```

Which references `ravenclaw-dark.scss` and `ravenclaw-light.scss` files that look like this:

```
$color-background: #fff !important;          /* Main background */
$color-text: #000 !important;                /* Main text (contrast bg) */

$color-background-alt: #b9b8b6 !important;   /* Alternate background */
$color-text-alt: #0E1A40 !important;         /* Alternate text */

$color-admin: #FEC601 !important;            /* CTAs & accents (main/opp txt ok) */
$color-accent-main: #1567B3 !important;      /* Good with main/opp text */
$color-accent-subtle: #8CA7B0 !important;    /* Subtle (main/opp text) */

$color-bad: #983C3C !important;              /* both text */
$color-good: #2C8431 !important;             /* both text */
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assets don't work that way, they're compiled into static files, they're not passed through the ruby logic each time. So in order to have what you want you would need to create an endpoint (in your `config/routes.rb`) that points to a controller action that returns a CSS file - and then you can have an ERB view that generates that CSS.

...but for this it's probably better to put that logic inside your layout file and just use the `stylesheet_link_tag` to pull in the different theme stylesheets. Take a look at the [Themes in Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11928476/152786) SO post for some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the sources!  I'll retool and ask a more pertinent question.